# Where are TFS Warehouse tables and how to access them directly?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to access warehouse of tfs to access the tables like 
1)table that stores the code requests submitted,approved,rejected
2)table that stores which employee submitted  the code or which team sumitted the code on
  what date the code is submitted
3)table that stores th e bugs raised,bugs which are open,bugs closed,bugs priority(p0,p1,p2,p3) and some other details

i want the output in the form as below

```
date  bugsClosed        bugsOpen           Reason
      p0 p1 p2 p3 total p0 p1 p2 p3 total  Active Fixed Postponed ByDesign ByRepro total
Jan   2  3  4  1  10    4  8  2  10 24     5       6     4         9        0       24
Feb   2  3  4  1  10    4  8  2  10 24     5       6     4         9        0       24
Mar   2  3  4  1  10    4  8  2  10 24     5       6     4         9        0       24
Apr   2  3  4  1  10    4  8  2  10 24     5       6     4         9        0       24
May   2  3  4  1  10    4  8  2  10 24     5       6     4         9        0       24
Jun   2  3  4  1  10    4  8  2  10 24     5       6     4         9        0       24
```

Thanks & Regards,
Srinivas P.

Answer (score 0):

Start here...  it will guide you to your answer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244696(v=vs.90).aspx

and here for a walk-through of the schema

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244711(v=VS.90).aspx

and here for writing custom reports on schema

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552(v=VS.90).aspx